# Rails I18n returns only some parts of the translation in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, locale, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm having problem with I18n in Rails, part of the translations he gets only part of the file.

My application.rb:

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
config.i18n.default_locale = :'pt-BR'
```

pt-BR.yml:

```
pt-BR:
  date:
    formats:
      default: ! '%d/%m/%Y'
      my_format: ! '%d de %B de %Y'
      short: ! '%d de %B'
  month_names:
  - 
  - Janeiro
  - Fevereiro
  - Março
  - Abril
  - Maio
  - Junho
  - Julho
  - Agosto
  - Setembro
  - Outubro
  - Novembro
  - Dezembro
```

View file:

```
<%= l news.created_at, :format => :my_format %>
```

View output:

```
11 de April de 2012
```

The correct view output should be:

```
11 de Abril de 2012
```

Rails rescued the "11 **de** April **de** 2012" and not got the month "11 de **April** de 2012"

Detail: In developing the translation is perfect, I'm having this problem only in production.

I'm using ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe month_names are only used for date_select and datetime_select tags.

Possible answer from http://i18n.lighthouseapp.com/projects/14947/tickets/12:

```
lt:
  date:
    order: [ :year, :month, :day ]
    formats:
      default: "%Y-%m-%d"
      short: "%b %d"
      long: "%B %d, %Y"
    day_names: [Sekmadienis, Pirmadienis, Antradienis, Trečiadienis, Ketvirtadienis, Penktadienis, Sekmadienis]
    abbr_day_names: [S, P, A, T, K, Pn, Š]
    month_names: [~, Sausis, Vasaris, Kovas, Balandis, Gegužė, Birželis, Liepa, Rugpjūtis, Rugsėjis, Spalis, Lapkritis, Gruodis]
    abbr_month_names: [~, Sau, Vas, Kov, Bal, Geg, Bir, Lie, Rugs, Rugp, Spa, Lap, Gruo]
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't now if this will help, but I usually get the proper locale template here:
https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale

Everything is working as expected.